# Index Error while trying to run a neural network

Tags: python, github, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am new to both python and neural networks.

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/mileyan/AnyNet)

First I did

> sh ./create_dataset.sh

And gave the correct path to scenflow_data_path.

Now I am trying to run this:

> python main.py --maxdisp 192 --with_spn

as given, I am getting this following error. Please let me know how to correct this.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 194, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 51, in main
    args.datapath)
  File "/home/kbdp5524/Downloads/AnyNet-master/dataloader/listflowfile.py", line 23, in dataloader
    monkaa_path = filepath + [x for x in image if 'monkaa' in x][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `[x for x in image if 'monkaa' in x]` returns no results. You cannot index an empty list

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. What do I do next?